# Ratingbar in Recyclerview not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ratingbar

I have a `Recyclerview` that holds `ratingbar` in list_items

If I user  **rtBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener** , then I get not results , nothing happens in rating bar , not even clickable

If I use **rtBar.setOnTouchListener** , it works , but my code does't works when clicked on 4th start

```
public EmployeeViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    rtBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            utilMethods.showToast(mContext, "" + rating);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your RatingBar is not clickable then check in your xml file where RatingBar has attribute `android:isIndicator="false"`.

> If **isIndicator** is **true** then you couldn't able to rate

Comment: although it is very old question, but this thing work for me.

Answer (score 0):

use interface like that

```
 public interface OnRecordEventListener  {
       void onRatingBarChange(Record item,float value);
 }
```

you create ViewHolder pass listener into constructor like this.

```
 public ViewHolder(View itemView, OnRecordEventListener listener) {
          super(itemView);
          textViewTitle = (TextView)     itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
          ratingBar = (RatingBar)     itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar_rating);
          bar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new     RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,   boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
              listener.onRatingBarChange(mRecords.get(getLayoutPosition()),   rating);
            }
           }
          });
         }
```

And update in onCreateViewHolder

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
   View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, viewGroup, false);
            return new ViewHolder(v,mClickListener);
        }
```

you can use interface for other events also, you just need to add method into interface,implement it and bind in ViewHolder constructor.

UPDATE
Consider you are using *RecyclerView* in Activity

```
public class RecyclerActivity extends Activity implements OnRecordEventListener {
    // all institutionalization, callbacks, hook methods
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      // Initialization .....
      mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(...);
      // Passing this because this class implements interface
      mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(mRecord,this));
    }
    @Override
    void onRatingBarChange(Record item,float value) {
      // do Something
    }
 }
```

Comment: its not even clickable , what's the use of interface here ?

Comment: Try always to abstract such LISTENERS through interface, that you can reuse it later and maintain code easily.